# SVG Path detection from a file

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, dictionary, svg

I have the following HTML 5 code ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">

</script>
<style type="text/css">

path#Selection{
fill: black;
}
path#Selection:hover{
fill:blue;
}
</style>
</head> 
<body>

<object data="America" type="image/svg+xml" id="test"></object>

</body>
</html>
```

The svg file that I'm using was exported from gimp as ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="38.2361in" height="19.4444in"
 viewBox="0 0 2753 1400">
  <path id="Selection"
    fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"
    d="M 397.00,118.96
       C 397.00,118.96 414.00,115.96 414.00,115.96
         414.00,115.96 432.96,108.64 432.96,108.64
         432.96,108.64 441.04,107.73 441.04,107.73
</path>
</svg>
```

Unfortunately my path detection with css hover does not work if this sits in a seperate file. The path is however drawn and displayed with in my browser, no problem. The only way I have managed to get the path#Selection:hover to work is to embed the actual code in my HTML file as such ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">

</script>
<style type="text/css">

path#Selection{
fill: black;
}
path#Selection:hover{
fill:blue;
}
</style>
</head> 
<body>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="38.2361in" height="19.4444in"
 viewBox="0 0 2753 1400">
  <path id="Selection"
    fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"
    d="M 397.00,118.96
       C 397.00,118.96 414.00,115.96 414.00,115.96
         414.00,115.96 432.96,108.64 432.96,108.64
         432.96,108.64 441.04,107.73 441.04,107.73
</path>
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

This is however extremely inconvenient as I am building a large map to include many countries so I would rather that the svg remain in a separate file. How may I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the style:

```
<style type="text/css">

path#Selection{
fill: black;
}
path#Selection:hover{
fill:blue;
}
</style>
```

...inside the svg file. That works as long as you don't reference it with `<img>` or as a CSS background-image.

Alternatively, as you suggested yourself, you can include the svg inline in the HTML document. The thing is that styles don't apply across documents, only in the same document.

Comment: Gotchya. I think I might end up writing this up as a php script. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only real way that I found to do this was to make a seperate html file, throw the svg stuff into it and import it as an object into the html I want to keep clean.